# Will Gnome Window Rendering fixes be backported to Bionic Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, lts, mutter

Does anyone know officially if the recently identified bugs by Canonical's Daniel Van Vugt and applied fixes to GNOME and Mutter; will get backported to all Ubuntu LTS versions; in my case specifically Bionic Ubuntu 18.04?

High impact fixes described in these articles (possibly more)...

- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-Broken-Culling-Fix
- https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Gen9-GNOME-2020-Optimze

Comment: Security fixes are back-ported, however *duflu* has mostly been working on performance fixes, not security issues.  Some performance tweaks may make it make to the latest LTS, but that's currently *focal*/20.04.